# installing mediawiki on ourproject.org and managing mysql

Tags: mediawiki, mysql

i have registered a project at ourproject.org and requested a mysql dp,they answered at my email and said that i can acces relative information at home/users/my_user_name/dp.txt but it just directs me to my use page.

first:how can i access the dp ?
second:i want to install mediawiki on it but they say that i should install it to the web space of the project ,by web space do they mean the ftp server ?

third:i want to enable interwiki's(eg: en.wiki , es.wiki, ...etc) should this be configured during or after the installation of media wiki.

Answer (score 0):

On you third (second) question. Interwiki means between wiki's, meaning that it link from one wiki to the other. You can set up your other wiki's after you set up the first one.

Also when your wikis are basically the same, except for the fact that they are in different languages, you should refer to the interwiki links as interlanguage links.

About setting up the MediaWiki. You first need to set up a MySQL DB (I assume that is what you mean with dp?). Then you upload the MediaWiki files to your FTP server (it is recommended to do this to the /w folder). After this you can just visit your wiki (at ourproject.org/w) and set it up (including giving it the MySQL DB information).